# Django check form error code in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django 1.10 and trying to find a way to check the error code of a form inside of the template. So I tried a few things, like errors.as_data or errors.as_json, but I was unable to parse the different values (except by using javascript). Could it be something like this ?

```
<p>{% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
                    {{ value }}
                    {% if code == 'inactive_account'%}
                         // do some stuff
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
</p>
```

But I don't know how to get this error code. Any suggestion ?

PS : I know that a solution would be to do it inside of the view, but since I am using a django already-made one, I would prefer not to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary `form.errors` does not contain the `ValidationError` instances. You need to use the [`as_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data) method.

Note that you need to loop through the list of errors for each key, and then you can check the code.

```
{% for key, key_errors in form.errors.as_data.items %}
    {{ key }}
    {% for error in key_errors %}
        {% if error.code == 'inactive_account'%}
        // do some stuff
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh great, thanks ! Exactly what I was looking for. If I may just ask you a "newbie" question, what is the ".items" in "form.errors.as_data.items" for ? Where does it come from ?

Comment: The `form.errors.as_data()` method returns a dictionary (in a Django template you don't include the parentheses). Then [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) is a method for all Python dictionaries. We use it to loop through the dictionary's keys and values together.

Comment: Thank you very much again ! I'm not new to programming, but very new to python so thanks for telling me these concepts.

Answer (score -1):

There's also other way to check for the error code.
You can use [has_error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.has_error) to check for the error code.

```
{% form.has_error 'field_name' 'code' %}
```

***To check for non-field errors use NON_FIELD_ERRORS as the field parameter.***